# jQuery slider infinite scrolling not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, infinite-scroll

I'm trying to create a simple infinite scrolling jQuery slider.
The problem is that after reaching the 3rd image, the slider goes back to the first, going through all other images.

Here is the code: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Us9vU/1/)

```
$('#rightArrow').click(function() {
     currentPosition = currentPosition+1;
    sliderControls(currentPosition);
    $('#combined').animate({
      'marginLeft' : slideWidth*(-currentPosition)
    }); 
  });
```

I want to make it infinite cycle. After the 3rd image should be the first with the same animation.

Answer (score 0):

Creating an infinite cycle is not as easy as you might think. To create a good infinite slider, you will have to append new elements at the end of your slider, when it reaches the end. The items you append at the end can be removed from the front to get the best performance.

As there are many infinite scroll plugins around, you might want to try one:  http://megahitmag.com/free-infinite-scrolling-jquery-plugins/